# How to create a paid keyvalue store

Tags: contract-development, contract-design

I'd like to create a contract through which people can set publicly available **key:value** information in exchange for some Ether sent to me (the owner of the contract). 
This is to create a public decentralized database on which anyone can read and write, and the Ether cost would be to limit spam.

However, I'd like it to be free for all users to retrieve any **key** stored in the contract. My understanding of Ethereum is limited, is this possible?

Comment: do you still need any clarifications?

Answer (score 4):

> I'd like to create a contract through which people can set publicly
>   available key=value information

You can use a mapping to store data and public method to set values

> exchange for some Ether sent to me (the owner of the contract)

You can make the set method payable and check for an amount of Ether from sender

> I'd like it to be free for all users to retrieve any key stored in the
>   contract

You can create the function a `view` one so no cost or transaction invlolved in reading values

> is this possible?

Yes, This looks possible. It would look like below.

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;

contract Store {
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) public keyValStore;
    address payable public  owner; 
    uint storeFee;

    constructor(uint fee) public {
        owner = msg.sender;  // setting contract creator address as the owner
        storeFee = fee; // setting a store fee for to set values
    }

    function set(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) public payable {
        require(msg.value >= storeFee); // check if Ether value is greater than the store fee
        owner.transfer(msg.value); // transfer Ether to owner account
        keyValStore[key] = value; // setting the key value pair in mapping
    }

    function get(bytes32 key) public view returns (bytes32) {
        bytes32 val = keyValStore[key]; // get the relavant value for the given key
        return val;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible, here's an example key/value store contract to help you get started that requires 1 ether to set a key/value and anyone can read the data for free:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.22 <0.6.0;
contract Store {
    mapping(bytes32 => bytes32) private store;
    mapping(bytes32 => address) private authors;
    address private owner;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function set(bytes32 key, bytes32 value) public payable {
        require(msg.value == 1 ether);
        require(store[key] == 0 || authors[key] == msg.sender);
        store[key] = value;
        authors[key] = msg.sender;
    }

    function get(bytes32 key) public view returns(bytes32) {
        return store[key];
    }

    function withdraw(address payable receiver) public {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        receiver.transfer(address(this).balance);
    }
}
```

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf7e0caef5cd7a18d31343670b60ff463fa23d5c8